# Grails run-app "Property source name must contain at least one character"

Tags: grails

When I want to start my grails app using "`grails run-app`" I get the following message:

```
| Running Grails application
| Error 2014-02-25 10:28:12,493 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Property source name must contain at least one character
Message: Property source name must contain at least one character
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   695 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I am using Grails 2.3.4 on a clean system (`Mac OS X`).

If it's helpful, here is my `.bash_proifile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
GRAILS_HOME=/Applications/grails-2.3.4; 
export GRAILS_HOME
PATH=$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH; 
export PATH
```

The app works perfectly on 4 other computers.

Comment: Can you please run 'grails clean' and then 'grails run-app' two times (at the first time you will get this exception but the second time you will not get that)? I've encountered this issue too.

Comment: Another thing that worth a try: grails run-app --stacktrace, and post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Any luck solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This error text is misleading sometimes. Just try to put

```
app.name=MyAppName
```

into `application.properties` in your grails root directory.